# Get month and year as string from mysql date

Tags: mysql, date, extract

how can I get month name and year from **mysql date datatype** 
my date is stored like 2018-12-18 and I want output as Dec 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, "%b %Y") from table_name;
```

You can also find other date and time functions
[here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can try below using date_format() function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2018-12-18", "%b %Y");
```